# Product integral for differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, infinite-product

Consider the following expression $$e^{\int_{\mathcal{M}}\Omega}$$ where $\Omega$ is the top form on the $m$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}.~~$  How appropriate is it to represent the above expression as a product integral via $$e^{\int_{\mathcal{M}}\Omega} = \prod_{p\in \mathcal{M}} e^{\Omega}$$ where $p$ is a point in $\mathcal{M}$ .

Comment: Are the left- and right-hand sides even the same kind of object?

Comment: @Randall That is why I asked. Does such an expression make sense?

Comment: When $m=0$ and $\mathcal M$ is finite.

Comment: Slightly more generally, when $m=0$ and $\Omega$, viewed as a map $\mathcal{M}\to\mathbb{R}$, is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Why don't you start by telling us what $e^{\Omega(p)}$ means when $\Omega$ is an $m$-form?

Comment: @TedShifrin Whatever I wrote is just a proposal which needn't be correct. I am basically looking for some answers on what has been done about product integrals on manifolds in general, if such a thing even makes sense.

Comment: Could this be about Liouville QFT? I don't know about the subject but I think I read something like that is done in it, just curious about the context maybe it could help if more is given

Comment: @Dabed Can you provide the reference where you read it?

Comment: Sorry it was just a reddit [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/o1zt5m/mathematicians_prove_2d_version_of_quantum/h265urx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) not really a reference or source

Comment: @Randall I have written an answer to my own question. Can you please have a look and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider a Volterra-type of product integral (original proposal)
$$\prod_{a}^b(1+f(x)dx) = \exp\left({\int_{a}^b f(x)dx}\right)$$
Now, we can interpret $f(x)dx$ as a top-form on a 1-D manifold and therefore, with this understanding, we can see that $$e^{f(x)dx} = 1 + f(x)dx$$
Using this equality, we can now write
$$\prod_{a}^b(1+f(x)dx) = \prod_{a}^b \exp(f(x)dx)= \exp\left({\int_{a}^b f(x)dx}\right)$$
As one can see. it is now very intuitive to justify the second equality and in turn also justify Volterra's original proposal. Now, we may propose a generalization of the above to higher dimensions (specifically $m$-dimensions) and write
$$e^{\int_{\mathcal{M}}\Omega} = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{M}}e^{\Omega(p)}$$
for a top-form $\Omega$ on the $m$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ where $$e^{\Omega(p)} = 1+\Omega(p)$$ which is exactly what I proposed in my question. Hence, my proposal may be interpreted as a higher dimensional version of a Volterra-type product integral. I chose to work on the complete manifold $\mathcal{M}$ but I think it is very easy to generalize to an integration range over an open set $U \in \mathcal{M}$, just like in Volterra's original proposal.

Comment: I am not a mathematics student and my answer is in no way rigorous and complete. I have merely understood some part of this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral and tried to generalize and obtain some answer for my question. All criticisms and comments to my proposal are welcome.